# Outputting Huffman codes to file

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I have a program that reads a file and saves the frequency of each character. It then constructs a huffman tree based on each character's frequency and then outputs to a file the huffman codes for the tree.

So an input like "Hello World" would output this sequence to a file:

```
01010101 0010 010 010 01010 0101010 000 01010 00101 010 0001
```

This makes sense because the most frequent characters have the shortest codes. The issue is, this increases the file size ten-fold. I realized the reason why is because each 1 and 0 is being represented in memory as its own character, so they get each get expanded out to a byte of data.

I was thinking what I could do is convert each code (E.G. "010") to a character and save that to file - but that still would pad the code to be a byte long (Or mess it up if the code is longer than a byte).

How do I go about this? I can give code snippets if needed - I'm basically saving each code into a string so that's why the file's coming out so big (It's outputting each "bit" as a byte). If I were to convert the code to a long for example, then a code like 00010 would be represented as 2 and a code like 010 would also be represented as 2.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have to do it a byte (or a word) at a time. Maintain a byte which you fill with bits, and a record of how many bits have been filled in so far. When you get to 8, write the byte and start over with an empty one.

Comment: You'll also need a variable that can hold the largest size Huffman code. Rather than write one byte at a time, you could just append bytes of data into a buffer until the buffer is nearly full, then write out the filled bytes of data from the buffer, and copy the remaining unwritten data to the beginning of the buffer.